# How to create a subclass?

Tags: java, class, subclass, superclass, super

I'm kind of a beginner at coding and I've been looking all over the internet and nothing really comes out and gives me an example on how to use the extend method and how to properly use the **super()** method. I'm kind of stuck with this and wondering if someone could show or give me a good example. My project was to Define a class Diploma and its subclass DiplomaWithHonors, so that some statements display their academic achievements. Thanks for your help! Okay now that I took a "stab" at the problem I have a error with the return statement if anyone can help with that...

```
     public class Diploma
      {
       public String fullName;
       public String course;
       int output = Diploma();

        public Diploma(String name, String info)
         {
         fullName = name;
         course = info;
         }
        public String toString()
         {
          return "This certifies that \n" + fullName + " \n has completed a course in " + course;
           }
        }

         public class DiplomaWithHonors extends Diploma
      {
        public DiplomaWithHonors( String name, String info ) 
      {
        super( name, info );
      }
       public String toString() 
      {
      return "This certifies that \n" + fullName + " \n has completed a course in " +   course+ "\n*** with honors ***";
      }
        }
      public String toString()
       {
        Diploma[] diplomas = new Diploma[2];
        diplomas[ 0 ] = new Diploma("Murray Smith", "Gardening");
        diplomas[ 1 ] = new DiplomaWithHonors("Lisa Smith", "Evolutionary Psychology");

        for( int i = 0; i< diplomas.length; i++) 
        {
         System.out.println( diplomas[ i ] );
        }
       }
        return output;
       }
```

P.S Sorry about the style malfunction, I kind of messed up on the copy paste.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html contains exactly such an example. Furthermore, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: If coding-is-for-you, maybe you should try writing a little code. Take a stab at the problem and come back when you've run into an actual problem.

Comment: `class B extends A { ... }`. `super()` has to be the first statement within the constructor of the child if you want to invoke the parent's constructor. If the parent has a parametrized constructor you can pass those parameters within the `super(param1, param2, ...);`statement. If you want to invoke a specific method of the parent, use `super.methodOfParentToInvoke(...)` where `methodOfParentToInvoke(...)` is the parent's method you want to invoke

Comment: Thank you @Radiodef and Roman for the examples they make e understand superclass and subclasses a little bit better. Nathaniel I would if I had any idea, but if something comes up I'll make sure to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super` isn't a method; [it's a keyword.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)  Under certain contexts it may be *called* or *used* as a method, but it's really a keyword.  The link above will give you tons of helpful info about that, as well as some tidbits on inheritance.

That aside, what it sounds like is that you have a straightforward relationship between two entities:

- A `Diploma` should be the base entity that you're using; it holds information such as the recipient's name, their GPA, and what degree subject they're receiving it for.
- A `DiplomaWithHonors` sounds like it's a different type of honor for the differing GPA.

A **very** primitive structure may look something like this.  Assume fields are defined.

```
public class Diploma {
    public Diploma(String name, double GPA, String degreeField, DiplomaType diplomaType) {
        this.name = name;
        this.GPA = GPA;
        this.degreeField = degreeField;
        this.diplomaType = diplomaType;
    }
}

public class DiplomaWithHonors extends Diploma {
    public DiplomaWithHonors(String name, double GPA, String degreeField, DiplomaType diplomaType) {
        super(name, GPA, degreeField, diplomaType);
        calculateHonors();
     }
}
```

Notice that `super` in the context of a constructor has to be the **first** thing referenced inside of that constructor.

Comment: Thank you @Makoto, I would have never of thought of it like this, you've now made it all make a ton more sense.

Answer (score 0):

see this example's toString() methods

```
import java.util.List;


public class Diploma {
    private String student;

    public String getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(String student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Diploma [student=" + student + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        DiplomaWithHonors d1 = new DiplomaWithHonors();
        d1.setStudent("John");
        String[] achievements = {"Golden Medal","Silver Medal"};
        d1.setAchievements(achievements);

        System.out.println(d1);

        DiplomaWithoutAnyHonors d2 = new DiplomaWithoutAnyHonors();
        d2.setStudent("Doe");
        String[] homeworksDoneByStackOverflow = {"How to use super"};
        d2.setHomeworksDoneByStackOverflow(homeworksDoneByStackOverflow );

        System.out.println(d2);
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.Arrays;



public class DiplomaWithHonors extends Diploma {
    private String[] achievements;

    public String[] getAchievements() {
        return achievements;
    }

    public void setAchievements(String[] achievements) {
        this.achievements = achievements;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DiplomaWithHonors [achievements=" + Arrays.asList(achievements)
                + ", toString()=" + super.toString() + "]";
    }


}
```

and

```
import java.util.Arrays;



public class DiplomaWithoutAnyHonors extends Diploma{
    private String[] homeworksDoneByStackOverflow;

    public String[] getHomeworksDoneByStackOverflow() {
        return homeworksDoneByStackOverflow;
    }

    public void setHomeworksDoneByStackOverflow(
            String[] homeworksDoneByStackOverflow) {
        this.homeworksDoneByStackOverflow = homeworksDoneByStackOverflow;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DiplomaWithoutAnyHonors [homeworksDoneByStackOverflow="
                + Arrays.asList(homeworksDoneByStackOverflow) + ", toString()="
                + super.toString() + "]";
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you Leo for giving me some different ways to do it I really appreciate your work.

Comment: How does this demonstrate super()?